# How force Android MediaPlayer to use only one connection to download music?

Tags: android, streaming, mp3, media-player, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My problem is that new android ICS MediaPlayer now download a music in two step :

1) It send a get request to the http server and the server start sending the mp3 file:

```
GET /stream/test.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.30.113
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 4.0.3)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 19 Apr 2012 07:37:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Win64) PHP/5.3.8
Last-Modified: Sat, 03 Feb 2007 11:17:50 GMT
ETag: "6d0000000400e4-5b415f-428909c5e7a6b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 5980511
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
```

2) It close the first connection and reopen anotherone :

```
GET /stream/test.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.30.113
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 19 Apr 2012 07:37:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Win64) PHP/5.3.8
Last-Modified: Sat, 03 Feb 2007 11:17:50 GMT
ETag: "6d0000000400e4-5b415f-428909c5e7a6b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 5980511
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
```

So, how can i returned to the previous functionnality in android 2.3.3 when only one connection was used to download an mp3 ?

Thanks.

Edit : I can see that MediaPlayer is based on networkstate, in fact, depending on the speed of the connection : wifi or 3G the MediaPlayer use these two connections, but with EDGE it only use one.

I think it can explain why a lot of user talk about a long buffering time before a music start.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: It is strange, because I use localhost (127.0.0.1) from a locally broadcasting server on-device and it still does the dual connection mechanism

Comment: Does any one have any explanation for this behavior? I do not know why Android needs the second request and could not find the code in Android source.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same problem and i tried to just send data for the first connection.

GET /stream/test.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.30.113
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 4.0.3)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

And skip the second connection.

it works well for me 
hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, But it was my first way to go and it didn't work for me cause the media player realy close the connection :( !

Comment: In my case the first connection still  connected for some stream  links. If I send  data just for the second connection  error failed to prepare appears :(